# ¿Insertar valor de chekbox no seleccionado en arreglo ya se en cliente o servidor con el mismo nombre e insercion de forma dinamica?

Tags: php, jquery, base-de-datos, mariadb, array

Hola se que es algo muy sencillo de hecho he intentado resolver esto del lado del cliente pero decidí intentar realizar esto en la base de datos directamente para poder continuar con mi proyecto, agradecería me corrigieran mi codigo. El problema es con el campo etiquetado, es un checkbox que se almacena en un arreglo a estas altura no me importa en donde solo quiero solucionar mi problema ya sea en el cliente o en el servidor.

```
CREATE TABLE capturar_pedido (
cliente varchar(255) NOT NULL,
orden_de_compra varchar(255),
producto varchar(255) NOT NULL,
unidad varchar(255) NOT NULL,
cantidad double NOT NULL,
fecha_de_embarque Date NOT NULL,
notas varchar(255),
  etiquetado char(2) default 'n',

id_pedido BIGINT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (id_pedido)
)
```

Les dejo tambien el form

Inicio

```
    <br/><br/>


<form action="agregarpedidos.php" method="post" name="form1">




                    <div  class="container1">
                        <div align="left" class="espacio10">
                                         <strong>Cliente:</strong>
              <select required name="cliente">
 <?php
        echo '<option value="">Selecciona un cliente</option>';

                    $sql = "Select cliente from clientes";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['cliente'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>
 </select>

                <strong>Orden de compra</strong>
              <input type="text" name="orden_de_compra"  placeholder="orden de compra" required="required" maxlength="255"/>


<button class="add_form_field" id="botonagregarproducto" >Agregar producto &nbsp; <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span></button>
                        </div>

                                         <table class="table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>PRODUCTO</th>
    <th>UNIDAD</th> 
    <th>CANTIDAD</th>
          <th>FECHA DE EMBARQUE</th>
      <th>NOTAS</th>
      <th>ETIQUETADO</th>
      <th>Opciones</th>

  </tr>

                                             </table>
</div>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var wrapper         = $(".container1");
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field");


    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
                var selectproductos = "<?php $sql = "Select producto from productos"; $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['producto'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>";

            var selectunidades = "<?php $sql = "Select unidad from unidades";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['unidad'].'</option>';
       }
     ?> ";

          $(wrapper).children('table').append('<tr>   <td> <select required name="productos[]"><option value="">Selecciona un Producto</option>'+selectproductos+'</select><td><select required name ="unidad[]"><option value="">Selecciona una unidad</option>'+selectunidades+'</select></td><td><input type="text" class="inputancho" name="cantidad[]" placeholder="cantidad" required="required"/></td><td><input type="date"  name="fecha_de_embarque[]" required="required"/></td>  <td> <textarea  rows="2" cols="30" name="notas[]" id="notas" maxlength="255"></textarea> </td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="etiquetado[]" value="Si">   </td><td><a href="#" class="delete">Eliminar</a></<td></tr>'); //add input box

        }
  else
  {
  alert('You Reached the limits')
  }
    });

   $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); x--;
})
});

</script>



<input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="GetTextValue()" id="submit-pedidos" value="Enviar" class="bt"/>


    </form>
```

Y el codigo en php

```
<body>
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("resource/Database.php");

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {   
                $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
        $orden_de_compra = $_POST['orden_de_compra'];



            $productos= (is_array($_POST['productos'])) ? $_POST['productos'] : array();
        $unidad= (is_array($_POST['unidad'])) ? $_POST['unidad'] : array();

            $cantidad= (is_array($_POST['cantidad'])) ? $_POST['cantidad'] : array();

            $fecha_de_embarque= (is_array($_POST['fecha_de_embarque'])) ? $_POST['fecha_de_embarque'] : array();

            $notas = (is_array($_POST['notas'])) ? $_POST['notas'] : array();
            $etiquetado= (is_array($_POST['etiquetado'])) ? $_POST['etiquetado'] : array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($etiquetado); $i++)
{
    if ($etiquetado[$i] == null) $etiquetado[$i] = 'No';
}




    if(empty($cliente) || empty($orden_de_compra) || empty($productos) ||empty($unidad) ||empty($cantidad) || empty($fecha_de_embarque)  ) {

        if(empty($cliente)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Campo cliente esta vacio.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($orden_de_compra)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>orden de compra esta vacio.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($productos)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Campo producto esta vacio.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($unidad)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Campo unidad esta vacio.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($cantidad)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Campo cantidad esta vacio.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($fecha_de_embarque)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Fecha de embarque esta vacio.</font><br/>";
        }






        //link to the previous page
        echo "<br/><a href='javascript:self.history.back();'>Regresa</a>";
    } else { 
        // if all the fields are filled (not empty) 



        $insertStmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO capturar_pedido(cliente, orden_de_compra, producto, unidad, cantidad , fecha_de_embarque, notas, etiquetado) VALUES(:cliente, :orden_de_compra, :producto, :unidad, :cantidad , :fecha_de_embarque, :notas, :etiquetado)");
        $i=0;

    foreach ($productos as $producto) {


        $insertStmt->execute(array('cliente' => $cliente,'orden_de_compra' => $orden_de_compra,'producto' => $producto,'unidad' => $unidad[$i],'cantidad' => $cantidad[$i] ,'fecha_de_embarque' => $fecha_de_embarque[$i] ,'notas' => $notas[$i] ,'etiquetado' => $etiquetado[$i] ));
                        $i++;

    }

        // Alternative to above bindparam and execute
        // $query->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':email' => $email, ':age' => $age));

        //display success message
                header("Location: index.php");

    }
}

?>
</body>
```

**Captura**
[image: Captura del sistema]

Comment: no le estaras mandando un nulo a ese campo no?

Comment: @gbianchi Es un checkbox que lo mando sin seleccionar he tratado de tomar ese valor nulo y cambiarlo a por ejemplo el valor "NO" tanto en php como del lado del cliente con jquery o incluso en MariaDB, el problema principal es que el arreglo tiene el mismo name y va junto con otros inputs agregandose registro por registro lo cual me ha hecho la vida imposible, me han dado soluciones pero no me han funcionado, de hecho ya hice una pregunta con el mismo problema

Comment: @DanielTreviño Ya agregaste el Jquery.js? Porque no lo veo por ningun lado en tu código

Comment: @Cig Lo agrego aqui: include_once 'partials/headers.php';
 se me paso publicarlo pero si lo tengo en mi codigo, con jquery genero los inputs de forma dinamica, lo combine con php para por ejemplo usar los select si t epreguntas porque no uso radio en lugar de checkbox es porque contienen los mismos nombres y son parte del mismo form cada nuevo input generado serian dos nuevos input radio con el mismo nombre, se repetirían valores que es lo que tambien me sucede con el checkbox

Comment: @DanielTreviño el error te da porque al no enviarle nada al checkbox, no se crea la variable [etiquetado], es por esto que te marca undefined: index. Podrías solucionarlo agregando una variable oculta "hidden" que tenga el value por defecto, o en otro caso, recoger los valores mediante javascript

Comment: @Cig Si agrego el hidden me funciona con un solo valor pero al ser multiples inputs que el usuario puede crear o borrar con el mismo name despues me marca valores incorrectos, tambien estoy intentanto por medio de javascript if(this.checked)
  {
    $(this).prev().val('Y');
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).prev().val('N');
  }
}); Pero no se nada de javascript :(

Answer (score 0):

Por fin encontre algo que funciona aun con muchos inputs con su respectivo name duplicado y lo mejor lo resuelve con jquery, encontre la solucion en la version de ingles de este sitio, les dejo la solucion:

```
 <input type="hidden" class="checkbox_handler" name="is_admin[]" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is_admin_ck[]" value="1" />

$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    var checkbox_val = ( this.checked ) ? 1 : 0;
    $(this).siblings('input.checkbox_handler').val(checkbox_val);
});
```

y el link donde lo encontre https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked

Comment: de hecho tu solución es porque como generas contenidos dinámicos con "Append" estos no funcionan, por así decirlo, Entonces tienes que llamar a "document" totalmente para que busque de nuevo en toda la página y encuentre ese contenido que creaste dinamicamente. Saludos! Y si Javascript era la solución :D

Comment: @Cig Con que era ese maltido append jaja pues me quito el sueño y la  verdad no entiendo del todo el codigo quiero decir this.checked obviamente valida que el checkbox este seleccionado pero para empezar no se ni que hace el operador ? o los : yo solo remplace el 1   y 0 jaja ademas que el nombre de los arrays es diferente yo solo tengo uno en mi post y funciona asi que pienso que en algun punto realiza el intercambio del valor del hidden o si no no tengo idea de para que sirve ese input pues tengo entendido que tienen que ser iguales sus name

Comment: ese operador que haces referencia es un operador condicional ternario, comparado masomenos con un `if` te dice si tiene la propiedad "checked" a la variable "checkbox_val" asignale 1 en caso contrario, es decir, como un else, en este caso `:` asignale 0

Comment: @Cig ¿Que hay sobre el operador "?" ?

Comment: todo es completo `(condicion)?si cumple: si no cumple` el operador `?` es como el `if`